# mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/seekok/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi

Tags: php, process, fcgid, virtualmin

Recently my server started to consume more RAM. Running processes became 500+. This never happened to me over the pass year. I have VPS / 2GB / Ubuntu / Virtualmin.

Apache has `MaxClients 256` and default `ServerLimit` (256). The maximum number of user processes (`ulimit -u`) is 15891.

Error log file `/var/log/virtualmin`:

```
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/seekdl/fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi
```

`/var/log/apache2`:

```
server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients setting
[Sat Oct 27 17:17:25 2012] [error] FastCGI process 11916 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sat Oct 27 17:17:25 2012] [error] FastCGI process 12374 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
[Sat Oct 27 17:17:25 2012] [error] FastCGI process 11918 still did not exit, terminating forcefully
```

Comment: 256 is fairly high for a 2GB machine, I can't really see a way of raising it safely without stepping up to a VPS with more memory. Not sure about the fastcgi messages though, they don't sound normal to me but maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

Comment: it's ok thank you so much hope someone will help me with a fix :)

Comment: [`MaxClients` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxclients). In 2.3.13 renamed to [`MaxRequestWorkers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers), but the old name still works.

Comment: To me, it looks like you were under a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), or maybe [slashdotted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect), or just scraped by a dumb bot without rate limiting on a good connection.